# C++ JSON Parser

Tags: c++, json, c++11

For my class I am working on writing a JSON parser to go through a JSON array of music artist.
An example of what it would look like is:

```
 [ 
    { "artist_name" : "Beatle, The", 
     "real_name" : "Unknown", 
     "artist_id" : 82730,
      "profile": "A phenomenally successful..." 
     } 
   ]
```

We are not allowed to use any form of JSON parser library. I have been stuck on the following couple functions since Friday and I am not sure what is wrong.

```
void Artist::artistParsefromJSONstream(fstream &stream)
{
    readJSONarray(stream);
}

void Artist::readJSONarray(fstream &stream)
{
    char c;

    if (!(stream >> c) || c != '[')
    {
        cerr << "readJSONarray exit";
        exit(2);
    } // exit
    do
    {
        readJSONDataObject(stream);
        stream >> c;
    } while (c != ']');
}

void Artist::readJSONDataObject(fstream &stream)
{
    char c;

    if (!(stream >> c || c != '{'))
    {
      cerr << "JSON Data Object exit";
      exit(3);
    }
    do
    {
        readJSONDataItem(stream);
        stream >> c;
    } while (c != '}');

}

void Artist::readJSONDataItem(fstream &stream)
{
    char c;
    string key;

    if (!(stream >> c || c != '"'))
    {
        cerr << "Data item exit";
        exit(4);
    }
    key += c;

    do
    {
        stream.get(c);
        key += c;
    } while(c != '"');


    if (!(stream >> c) || c != ':')
    {
        cerr << "colon not found";
        exit(5);
    }
    stream >> c;

    if (isdigit(c))
    {
        stream.unget();
        int number;
        stream >> number;
    }
    else
    {
        if (key == "artist_name")
        {
            char x;
            string s;

            stream >> x;
            s += x;
            while(x != '"')
            {
                stream.get(x);
                s+=x;
            }

            _name = s;
            cout << _name << " \n";
        }
        if (key == "real_name")
        {
            char x;
            string s;

            stream >> x;
            while(x != '"')
            {
                s += x;
                stream.get(x);
            }

            _realName = s;
            cout << _realName << " \n";
        }

        if (key == "profile")
        {
            char x;
            string s;

            stream >> x;
            while(x != '"')
            {
                s+= x;
                stream.get(x);
            }

            _profile = s;
            cout << _profile << " \n";
        }

        if (key == "num_images")
        {
            char x;
            string s;

            stream >> x;
            while( x != '"')
            {
                _numImages += x;
                stream.get(x);
            }

            cout << _numImages << " \n";
            _numImages = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Desired Output:

```
Beatles, The  
Unknown  
A phenomenally successful ...
```

then moving onto the next object in the array.

Actual output:

```
eatles, The"  
colon not found
```

Any advice on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Inconsistent formatting and poor code quality are brothers in crime. Fix the formatting, and you'll instantly solve an entire class of common mistakes.

Comment: For a start, your `key` variable is read in a way that puts the surrounding double quotes into the `key` string, but you compare them to a la `if (key == "artist_name")`: it should be `if (key == "\"artist_name\"")`.  You could see this kind of thing yourself if you put in `std::cout << "key is '" << key << "'\n";` temporarily, to help you debug.

Comment: " not allowed to use any form of JSON parser" - that generally means no _existing_ parser. The exercise is to write your own. Part of the problem with your code is that you mix parsing and interpretation of the JSON. Your parser shouldn't know anything about `"artist"`, That's a problem for another class. IOW, it means that `class Artist` shouldn't be a JSON parser as well.

Comment: That's really a strange mix of GNU coding style, Linux (the Kernel) coding style, Allman coding style and some more. Be consistent; the less you need to concentrate on style, the more capacity you have for debugging.

Comment: JSON parsing is done usually with recursion, when you find a token which has special meaning to JSON (aka '[','{' etc.) you recouse the function to start parsing from that location and return the parsed json to the caller-parsing function